# Why do none of my check buttons stay checked?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I've been trying to code some check buttons for a program I'm creating for a school project (please ignore the fact it's organs lmao). So, when I try to code these checkbuttons they all format and appear correctly with the value set to off as I wanted but then it won't allow me to click on the checks and I'm not sure why? The checkmark appears momentarily when I click and then if I hold, it will stay there until I take my finger off the mouse but then will disappear again when I do. Not sure what's happening but here's the code:

```
checkbutton_frame=tkinter.Frame(frame1, bg="#0073CF")
checkbutton_frame.grid(row=5,column=0)

liver_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
liver_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Liver", font=("Calibri",20), 
fg="#FFFFFF", variable=liver_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
liver_check.grid(row=0, column=0)

heart_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
heart_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Heart", font=("Calibri",20), 
fg="#FFFFFF", variable=heart_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
heart_check.grid(row=0, column=1)

lungR_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
lungR_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Lung(R)", font=("Calibri",20), 
fg="#FFFFFF", variable=lungR_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
lungR_check.grid(row=0, column=2)

lungL_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
lungL_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Lung(L)", font=("Calibri",20), 
fg="#FFFFFF", variable=lungL_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
lungL_check.grid(row=0, column=3)

kidneyR_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
kidneyR_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Kidney(R)", font=("Calibri",20), fg="#FFFFFF", variable=kidneyR_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
kidneyR_check.grid(row=0, column=4)

kidneyL_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
kidneyL_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Kidney(L)", font=("Calibri",20), fg="#FFFFFF", variable=kidneyL_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
kidneyL_check.grid(row=0, column=5)

pancreas_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
pancreas_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Pancreas", font=("Calibri",20), fg="#FFFFFF", variable=pancreas_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
pancreas_check.grid(row=1, column=2)

sbowel_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
sbowel_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Small Bowel", font=("Calibri",20), fg="#FFFFFF", variable=sbowel_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
sbowel_check.grid(row=1, column=3)

cornea_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
cornea_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Cornea", font=("Calibri",20), fg="#FFFFFF", variable=cornea_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
cornea_check.grid(row=1, column=4)

for widget in checkbutton_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(pady=5, padx=10)
```

Have found myself really confused especially since I've sampled this code from another program I have and it works there and I can't seem to find any differences in the code. Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Similar questions have been asked before. Did you search this site for an answer?

Comment: It is because the color of the tick is "#FFFFFF" (same as `fg` option) so you cannot see it when the background is also white.  Try using different `fg` color or set `selectcolor` (the background color of the box) to other color.

Answer (score 0):

Since the color of the tick are in white which is the same as the tick box, so it looks invisible.

You can either set `fg` (the tick) or `selectcolor` (the tick box) to other color.

Below code set `fg="black"` of the first checkbox ("Liver") and `selectcolor="black"` of the second checkbox ("Heart"):

```py
liver_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
liver_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Liver", font=("Calibri",20),
fg="black", variable=liver_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF")
liver_check.grid(row=0, column=0)

heart_var=tkinter.StringVar(value=0)
heart_check=tkinter.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Heart", font=("Calibri",20),
fg="#FFFFFF", variable=heart_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, bg="#0073CF",
selectcolor="black")
heart_check.grid(row=0, column=1)
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> So, when I try to code these checkbuttons they all format and appear
> correctly with the value set to off as I wanted but then it won't
> allow me to click on the checks and I'm not sure why?
>
> The checkmark appears momentarily when I click and then if I hold, it
> will stay there until I take my finger off the mouse but then will
> disappear again when I do

Used `ttk` is more advancement than `tkinter`. You don't need to add keywords to parameters for every widget, such as `fb`, `bg`, `font`, etc. Just using `ttk.Style()` will save you all duplicate keywords in parameter.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


win = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("Blue.TCheckbutton", foreground="#FFFFFF", background="#0073CF")
style.configure("Calibri.TCheckbutton", font=('Sans','10','bold'))

frame1 = tk.Frame()
frame1.pack()

checkbutton_frame= tk.Frame(frame1, bg="#0073CF")
checkbutton_frame.grid(row=5,column=0)

liver_var = tk.StringVar()
liver_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Liver" , 
variable=liver_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
liver_check.grid(row=0, column=0)
liver_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

heart_var = tk.StringVar()
heart_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Heart", 
variable = heart_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
heart_check.grid(row=0, column=1)
heart_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

lungR_var = tk.StringVar()
lungR_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Lung(R)",
                              variable=lungR_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
lungR_check.grid(row=0, column=2)
lungR_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

lungL_var = tk.StringVar()
lungL_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Lung(L)",
                             variable=lungL_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
lungL_check.grid(row=0, column=3)
lungL_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

kidneyR_var = tk.StringVar()
kidneyR_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Kidney(R)",
                                        variable=kidneyR_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
kidneyR_check.grid(row=0, column=4)
kidneyR_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

kidneyL_var = tk.StringVar()
kidneyL_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Kidney(L)",
                                   variable=kidneyL_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
kidneyL_check.grid(row=0, column=5)
kidneyL_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

pancreas_var = tk.StringVar()
pancreas_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Pancreas",
                                    variable=pancreas_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
pancreas_check.grid(row=1, column=2)
pancreas_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

sbowel_var = tk.StringVar()
sbowel_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Small Bowel",
                               variable=sbowel_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
sbowel_check.grid(row=1, column=3)
sbowel_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

cornea_var = tk.StringVar()
cornea_check = ttk.Checkbutton(checkbutton_frame, text="Cornea",
                                  variable=cornea_var, onvalue=1, offvalue=0)
cornea_check.grid(row=1, column=4)
cornea_check.configure(style="Blue.TCheckbutton")

for widget in checkbutton_frame.winfo_children():
    widget.grid_configure(pady=5, padx=10)

 
 
win.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]